# Use GCM Registration ID for CRUD operations on database as unique ID?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am communicating with database using web service, in which I am doing insert, update, retrieve and delete on records on the server. There are only two fields that I am using : id, text. I wanted to ask that can I use the gcm registration ID as the unique device ID to store in the id field in my database or should I use other ids as IMEI number for CRUD operations and use completely other web service to just register the GCM registration ID.

As I have heard that GCM registration IDs tend to refresh and regenerate as well sometimes comes null, so it may not be a good idea to store it as unique id of a record in database.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable views..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCM registration ID is not a good candidate for a primary key in the database for several reasons :

1. It's long (typically 100-200 bytes, and according to Google it can be as large as 4096 bytes). At least in some databases you won't be able to define an index on that column.
2. If your server is serving multiple appications, each device will have multiple registration IDs (one for each application).
3. If a user uninstalls and re-installs the app, a new registration ID may be assigned for that app.

You should generate your own id and use it instead (either a UUID, a DB sequence or something else).

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to use `IMEI` number.

Answer (score 0):

GCM id can be changed. So its better, dont use it as UNIQUE ID. You may user UUID.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html